# Public Cursor getAll error Android

Tags: android

I'm doing a final project for my university, and I'm getting a strange error.
In Eclipse it says everything is ok, but when I run the program when trying to access this function in the database adapter the program crashes:

```
public Cursor getAllProjectsCursor() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[] {
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_PROJ_NAME,
                            KEY_BEG_DATE
                    }, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);

}
```

but if instead I just put like this, the program runs normally:

```
public Cursor getAllProjectsCursor() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[] {
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_PROJ_NAME
                    }, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
}
```

I want to pass all column values, and I think all the building is good. It's the same for all columns.

Can you help me?

---

In debug it says that:

```
INFO/Database(677): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: beg_date
```

In my code I have:

```
public class PMDBAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PocketManager.db";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Projects";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            private SQLiteDatabase db;
            public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
            public static final String KEY_PROJ_NAME = "proj_name";
            public static final int PROJ_NAME_COLUMN = 2;
            public static final String KEY_AREA = "proj_area";
            public static final int AREA_COLUMN = 3;
            public static final String KEY_BEG_DATE = "beg_date";
            public static final int BEG_DATE_COLUMN = 4;
            public static final String KEY_END_DATE = "end_date";
            public static final int END_DATE_COLUMN = 5;
            public static final String KEY_PERC = "perc";
            public static final int PERC_COLUMN = 6;

            private final Context context;
            private ProjDBOpenHelper dbHelper;
```

and:

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +
    DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
           + KEY_PROJ_NAME + " text not null, "
           + KEY_AREA + "text not null, " 
           + KEY_BEG_DATE + "long, "
           + KEY_END_DATE + "long, "
           + KEY_PERC + " integer);";
```

Comment: Can you provide a `logcat` output of the error during the crash?

Comment: Also, are you missing a comma between `KEY_PROJ_NAME` and `KEY_BEG_DATE` in the portion of the code that's crashing for you?

Comment: You don't have a space before `"long, "` for `KEY_BEG_DATE` and `KEY_END_DATE`. 
Change those strings to `" long, "` because the way it is now those columns are getting named `"beg_datelong"` and `"end_datelong"`.  That also seems to be the case with `KEY_AREA`, put a space before `" text not null, "` for that one too!

Answer (score 3):

change

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                     KEY_ID,
                     KEY_PROJ_NAME
                     KEY_BEG_DATE}, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null);

        }
```

to

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                     KEY_ID,
                     KEY_PROJ_NAME,
                     KEY_BEG_DATE}, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null);

        }
```

Eclipse typically won't pick up on errors in your database query strings.

Comment: don't you hate how hitting `Enter` in here sends the comment before you're ready ><

Comment: yeah its true xD i posted the rest of the answer its a strange error im freaking i just want to get this done xD

Answer (score -1):

```
public Cursor getAllDataDays() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MYBUDGETWITHDAYS;
    return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code answers the question?